# 404 Error on GCP App Engine Static Files via API Gateway

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, http-status-code-404, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have a node.js app deployed in App Engine. And I have my API Gateway setup in-front to route to that app.

API Config(yaml)

```
paths:
  /hello:
    get:
      summary: Hello
      operationId: hello
      x-google-backend:
        address: <url_from_appengine>
        jwt_audience: <my_jwt_key>
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
```

When trying to access the app via the API Gateway URL + the path configured in the api config (https://my-gateway.gateway.dev/hello), I am getting a 404 error for the following static files, but I think I am getting to the page as I am seeing its page title and just a white page:

- https://my-gateway.gateway.dev/static/css/main.xxxxxxxx.css
- https://my-gateway.gateway.dev/static/js/main.xxxxxxxx.js
- https://my-gateway.gateway.dev/manifest.json

But when I tried accessing my app directly from the App Engine, there is no issue at all. Am I missing something on my API Config routing?

Below is my app.yaml and file structure.

app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs14
service: my-app

- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html

- url: /(.*)/$
  static_files: build/\1/index.html
  upload: build/.*/index.html

- url: /(.*\.(css|js|json|gif|eot|png|jpg|jpeg|ico|svg|xml|woff|woff2))$
  static_files: build/\1
  upload: build/.*\.(css|js|json|gif|eot|png|jpg|jpeg|ico|svg|xml|woff|woff2)$

- url: /.*
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
```

```
build
│
│───index.html
|───manifest.json
|───favicon.ico
│ 
└───static
│   │
│   └───css
│       │───styles.css
│       js
│       │───scripts.js
```

Comment: Show us the contents of your ```app.yaml``` file

Comment: Hi @NoCommandLine, thank you for your response. I just added the app.yaml file and the file structure.